# Android Socket Creation Failure

Tags: android, sockets

I have this method to start a socket connetion so that I can chat between my PC and Phone.  Already have a server on my PC that is awaiting connection from Android.

```
private void connectToServer() throws IOException
    {
        showMessage("Starting Connection...");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 0511);
        showMessage("\n Connection Established: "+connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }
```

And this is the error I get when I run it:

```
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jister13.chattest/com.jister13.chattest.ChatRoom}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:565)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at com.jister13.chattest.ChatRoom.connectToServer(ChatRoom.java:88)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at com.jister13.chattest.ChatRoom.startRunning(ChatRoom.java:74)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at com.jister13.chattest.ChatRoom.onCreate(ChatRoom.java:69)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
03-08 19:02:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2524):     ... 11 more
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: Did any of the hundreds of matching questions on StackOverflow not help when you search for that error?

Answer (score 2):

Read the error that's contained in the exception being thrown!

`Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

It has thrown an exception because you've attempted to do a networking operation on the main UI thread. In Android, you must do any time-consuming tasks (networking, database access, lengthy number crunching, and so on) off the UI thread.

You need to perform this on a separate, non-UI thread.

Comment: How do I do this then because I have no idea what to do from this point.

Comment: Read a tutorial regarding performing a networking function on a separate thread. An AsyncTask tutorial may be a good start. Seriously, without trying to sound an arse, you need to help yourself a bit more here and do research and learning. Only ask on StackOverflow when you have shown some effort and you're still really stuck.